# Why won't my chat component render on the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

My chat component will not render on the page here is the code and at the bottom are the error messages. If you need I can reply to a comment with my router page event though there does not appear to be anything wrong with my App.js:

```
const SidePanel = () => {
        const style = {
            main: `flex flex-col p-[10px]`
        }
        const scroll = useRef();
        const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
        useEffect(() => {
            const q = Query(doc(db, 'messages', orderBy('timestamp')))
            const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
                let messages = []
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    messages.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
                })
                setMessages(messages)
            })
        })
        // function onProfilePictureClick() {
        //     // change style/add class to show small profile screen with name, email, when user was created and link to go to profile page
        // }
    return (
        <div>
            <main className={style.main}>
                <aside>
                    <p>Sam</p>
                </aside>
                {/* <img alt="userProfileImage"  className="userPhoto" src="https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/me" />  */}
                {/* make above image circular and if user has no image use default image */}
                {messages && messages.map((message) => {
                    return (
                        <Livechat key={message.id} message={message} />
                    )
                })}
            </main>
            <SendMessage scroll={scroll} />
            <span ref={scroll}></span>
        </div>
    );
};
export default SidePanel;
```

[image: console errors]

```
export const db = getFirestore();
```

Comment: Here is my App.js:
function App() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="signin" element={<Signin />}/>
            <Route path="signup" element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
            <Route path="chat" element={<SidePanel />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }

  export default App;

Comment: There appears to be a malformed firebase document value used in your code.

Comment: could you probably check the args passed to the firebase collection. There is a certain format the first argument is supposed to be (as inferred from the initial error context)

Answer (score 0):

Your Firestore query should be a **collection reference** not a **document reference**. According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web-version-9_1):

> Cloud Firestore provides powerful query functionality for specifying which documents you want to retrieve from a **collection** or **collection group**.

As stated, your query should be like this:

```
const q = query(collection(db, 'messages', orderBy('timestamp')))
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    let messages = []
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        messages.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
    })
    setMessages(messages)
})
```

Comment: It still displays the same error message after doing that.

Comment: Include in the question how you passed the `db` on your component. I suspect that the `db` is giving that error.